# React Native Share not working after the android sdk upgrade to >=30

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-share

Not able to share after android sdk upgrade.React Native Share not working on android devices intermittently. Using version "react-native": "~0.63.0"

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to the android sdk version >=30, you will have to add the query parameter of all the apps you want to share to.

```
 <queries>
    <package android:name="com.google.android.youtube" />
    <package android:name="com.facebook.katana" />
    <package android:name="com.facebook.orca" />
    <package android:name="com.facebook.mlite" />
    <package android:name="com.facebook.lite" />
    <package android:name="org.telegram.messenger" />
    <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
  </queries>
```

This code snipet is for istagram, telegram, facebook and whatsapp.